# Where has a4j:support to be embedded to be working?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

When I emebed a `a4j:support` tag inside a `rich:panel` tag, AJAX is working. When it's not embedded in it, AJAX it's not working.

When I emebed a `a4j:support` tag inside a `h:panel` tag, AJAX is not working. When it's embedded in a n`a4j:form` tag, it's not working.

Is there a rule to where RichFaces tags with AJAX functionality have to be embedded to be working?

Answer (score 4):

a4j:support should work with any jsf component that can fire the javascript event specified in the event attribute:

```
<a4j:support event="specified event" .../>
```